# Android Studio terminates execution with gradle script error after new image added to res/drawable

Tags: java, android

Andriod studio terminates execution with gradle script error after new image added to res/drawable

```
C:\Users\Admin\AndroidProjects\Wolf\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\logo.pngError:Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 42
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> C:\Users\Admin\AndroidProjects\Wolf\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\logo.png: Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 42

Comment: what is the value of buildToolsVersion in build.gradle

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0' @Kesh1234

Comment: you have two files with name build.grade not the one under grade folder. Other one, change the buildToolsVersion to 22.0.0 and try again

Comment: Also try by changing the extension of your images from png to jpeg, if you had modified it while copying the image to Android Studio.